# sudo apt update on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, updates

I have Ubuntu installed on an external Hard

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

[image: Ubuntu Version]

I get an error when trying sudo apt update

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                      
Hit:3 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                                     
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://deb.anydesk.com/dists/all/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

[image: error1]

Or even when I use the command sudo apt-get update:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                  
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                           
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://deb.anydesk.com/dists/all/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

[image: error2]

I also checked the instuctions in [sudo apt update Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372928/error-for-sudo-apt-get-update-on-ubuntu-20-04) but it looks hopeless

I also checked the answer in question suggested in the comment:

[What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

and ran the code

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/trusty-media

sudo apt-get update
```

but got the same error

Could it be that my  --Hit:1 http://de.archive--  be the problem?

Comment: Read your messages; http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ does **not** support *jammy*  (please provide text, rather than pictures of text).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to programs menu or press windows from keyboard to show it.
2. Choose software and updates program or search it in the menu to appear and open it.
3. Make sure that update options are marked in these tabs "Ubuntu software and update" you can also take a look at other software tab in the same programe.
4. After you mark boxes that will ask password click close , the click reload from the new window and wait till it finish updating cache, after that try to update in terminal.